# Вопрос о компиляции объектных файлов в Си

Tags: c

Я пишу библиотеку, внутри всё выглядит примерно так:
Пользовательская программа > библиотека > модуль библиотеки
(gcc -shared -fPIC -o liblib.so lib.c module.c)

В модуле реализуются определённые функции, которые используются в библиотеке, но я не хочу, чтобы эти функции могли быть использованы в пользовательской программе, они должны быть static. Как сделать их статическими?
Если в библиотеке будет заголовок:

```
static void function();
```

А в модуле реализация:

```
void function() {...}
```

То ничего не выйдет. Из-за static в заголовке сам заголовок теряет связь с телом в модуле. Если указать static в модуле, то библиотека не будет его видеть. Без static в библиотеке функция не будет статичной.

Comment: Не описывайте их в h-файлах, а только в файлах реализации - как `extern void function();` - только имена надо давать такие странные :), чтоб случайной коллизии не было. Тогда внешние модули о них и подозревать не будут...

Comment: Если вы понимаете, что значит *static* для функций, то понимаете и бесполезность такого использования в библиотеке. Вариант — определить в заголовке тело функции как *static inline* вместе с реалиацией.